# How to manually install dhcpcd?

Tags: raspbian-jessie, dhcp, services

I upgraded wheezy to jessie and there is no dhcpcd installed. I installed it with `apt-get install dhcpcd` but I cannot start the service. When I do `sudo service dhcpcd start` I get `Failed to start dhcpcd.service: Unit dhcpcd.service failed to load: No such file or directory.`
Is there a way to manually install dhcpcd?

Comment: What service do you want to start? `dhcpcd` is a DHCP client.

Comment: Which runs as a daemon service: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dhcpcd

Comment: So maybe you are looking for `dhcpcd5` package?

Comment: `systemctl enable dhcpcd@eth0` (if it is eth0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do `sudo apt-get install dhcpcd5`

Comment: Does that also start the service?

Comment: @Ghanima: Yes it does.

Comment: Ok, cool.... :)

Comment: Installing worked but now there is an error: `â— dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-02-22 20:25:52 CET; 1min 13s ago
  Process: 416 ExecStart=/sbin/dhcpcd -q -b (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`

Comment: `Feb 22 20:25:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Feb 22 20:25:49 raspberrypi dhcpcd[416]: Usage: dhcpcd [options] <interface>
Feb 22 20:25:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 22 20:25:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Feb 22 20:25:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit dhcpcd.service entered failed state.`

Comment: @Reto: Did you removed old `dhcpcd` package? I think you messed up a little your installation, because this message: `dhcpcd[416]: Usage: dhcpcd [options] <interface>` looks like system tried to run `dhcpcd` from `dhcpcd` package, not from `dhcpcd5` package. Just `apt-get remove dhcpcd` and you'll be fine.